# What happens when you initialize a C++ object by assignment?

Tags: c++, object, initialization, variable-assignment

From what I understand, assignment uses the `operator=` function, and initialization uses the contsructor. But when you assign another object during declaration, what happens? I would have thought that `car2` would initialize with `car1`'s data, but I can't tell. Does it initialize with the default constructor first, and then re-assign the data? I tried writing a quick program and traced it with a debugger, but it wouldn't let me look through the important line `Car car2 = car1`. I've included my program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Car
{
public:
    Car();
    Car(std::string color, std::string make);

private:
    std::string color;
    std::string make;
};

Car::Car() {
    this->color = "None";
    this->make = "None";
}

Car::Car(std::string color, std::string make) {
    this->color = color;
    this->make = make;
}

int main() {
    Car car1("blue", "Toyota");
    Car car2 = car1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See [Copy constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) *"The copy constructor is called whenever an object is initialized (by direct-initialization or copy-initialization) from another object of the same type ..."*

Comment: Initialisation can be done with `=`, but it’s not an assignment. It’s very common in C++ that a symbol or keyword has multiple meanings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Car` has an [implicitly declared copy-ctor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor), which is used here as the ctor-call cannot be elided (it is not initialized with a pr-value), nor is move-construction possible (it is not an xvalue).

That implicitly-declared copy-ctor does member-wise copy-construction.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the links!